# index.js missing in VS Pro 2017 RC Cordova Typescript tutorial

Tags: cordova, typescript

Working on VS Pro 2017 RC Cordova tutorial. Can't find www\scripts\index.js to edit at the "Add the Find Weather Button Click Listener" section. Built app as TypeScript|Mobile Apps|Blank App (Apache Cordova). VS Pro 2017 RC, VisualStudio/public.d15rel/15.0.26020.0

Comment: What happens if you add the file?

Comment: Not sure what to put in it, need to look into this...